# Replacing Collection's ID with Value in an AngularJS Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, smart-table

I need to use the textual value of an "enumeration" in an AngularJS table (I use here the Smart Tables but it can be anything)

My enumeration is like this: `var team = { "0": "Alpha", "1": "Beta", "2": "Gamma" };`

and my `person` is like `{id: personId, firstName: "string",..., team: teamId}`

[image]

Here is [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/PKqVNJ)

So, from one part in *Person* I have the `teamID`, from the other part I can get the Teams json (`{ "0": "Alpha", "1": "Beta", "2": "Gamma" }`)

How can I "join" that info to display team names in the table?

More generally speaking the problem is the following:

> I have a collection of objects `A` that contains IDs of object `B`. I need to display in the `A` collection table the `B` Name instead of the `B` Id...

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code on line 29 by this..

```
var mood = moods[Math.round(Math.random()).toString()];
```

Comment: that code just generates fake persons. In the real project I have an ID, not the string, this is the problem :)

Comment: The id must be mapped to a String right. Just add the mapping code or if can share the full scenario.

Comment: I have a collection of objects `A` that contains IDs of object `B`. I need to display in the `A` collection table the `B` Name instead of the `B` Id...

Comment: If you look closely that is what I have done. B["id"] will return value. you can get the ID from A.

Comment: Imagine I obtain the Person collection from a call to external API. I can't modify it structure. var mood should be always an id. I can transform it on my side, but the initial value is "0" or "1", not "Alpha" or "Beta"

Comment: So what is the problem. Why don't just get the values by mapping them with the ID.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you propose me to create a new collection `persons1` from `persons` where team will be `name` instead of `id`?

Answer (score 1):

The Ashish answer gave me a solution consisting in creating the clone collection with mapped members...

```
vm.persons2 = vm.persons.map(function(p){p.team = teams[p.team]; return p;});
```

and

```
<table ... st-safe-src="vm.persons2" ...>
```

like [in the CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/MvwRVG)